# Objectify embedded array inside an embedded array can't persist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

My Class heirarchy is as follows
School - contains list of Employees - which contains list of qualifications
Employees is an Embedded list in School. I can persist a School with it's employees no problem.  Now when I add the list of qualifications to an employee as an embedded field I get the following error

You cannot nest multiple @Embedded arrays or collections

The objectify documentation seems to indicate I should be able to do this provided the objects are serializable which they are.  Am I missing something? If this is the way it works is there a way around it?

Update:

School Class

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;

    @Entity
    @SuppressWarnings("serial") 
    public class School implements Serializable
    {
        @Id
        private String title;

        @Embedded
        private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        public School ()
        {       
        }
        public School (String title)
        {       
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void addEmployee( Employee employee )
        {
            this.employees.add(employee);
        }
    }
```

Employee Class

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;

    @Entity
    @SuppressWarnings("serial") 
    public class Employee implements Serializable
    {
        @Id
        private String title;

        @Embedded
        private List<String> qualifications = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Employee ()
        {       
        }
        public Employee (String title)
        {       
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void addQualification( String qualification )
        {
            this.qualifications.add(qualification);
        }
    }
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot nest multiple @Embedded arrays or collections. A second was found at private java.util.List com.app.nquizitive.shared.Employee.qualifications
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.EmbeddedMultivalueFieldSaver.<init>(EmbeddedMultivalueFieldSaver.java:36)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.EmbeddedCollectionFieldSaver.<init>(EmbeddedCollectionFieldSaver.java:21)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.ClassSaver.<init>(ClassSaver.java:64)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.EmbeddedMultivalueFieldSaver.<init>(EmbeddedMultivalueFieldSaver.java:43)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.EmbeddedCollectionFieldSaver.<init>(EmbeddedCollectionFieldSaver.java:21)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.ClassSaver.<init>(ClassSaver.java:64)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.save.ClassSaver.<init>(ClassSaver.java:29)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.<init>(Transmog.java:322)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.<init>(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:75)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.register(Registrar.java:69)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.register(ObjectifyFactory.java:209)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.register(ObjectifyService.java:38)
at com.app.nquizitive.server.dao.SchoolDao.<clinit>(SchoolDao.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different annotations:

- @Embed (@Embedded in ofy3)
- @Serialize (@Serialized in ofy3)

If you want something to serialize, use the second. If you want something embedded, use the first. You can't nest @Embed(ded) lists, but you can put a @Serialize(d) list inside an embedded list.

Comment: I have added my code to the OP.  Basically I can persist a school object fine so long as the Employee class has no Qualifications list in it, other wise I get the error shown at the bottom of the OP.  I have tried the Employees Qualification list with and without the Embedded annotation.

Comment: Get rid of the Embedded annotation. It is not appropriate for lists of primitive types; Embedded causes Objectify to treat the type as an class (breaking it down by field) instead of a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Which of the classes above are annotated with @Entity?  It sounds like School is a datastore entity, while Employees are not (i.e. they are just serialized into School) and qualifications are not (i.e. they are just serialized into Employees).

The Objectify annotation of @Embedded isn't needed/relevant/allowed, in a non-Entity class.

Comment: They are both entitys.  I have tried it with the Employee having the @Entity annotation and without it.  It just does not seem to like the List in the child Entity/class